# character entered by a user is a vowel or consonant, using if else statement

Tags: javascript

Please suggest what's wrong with the code??

```
<script>
var chrctr = prompt("Enter a character");

    if (a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u') {
        document.write("Is a Vowel");
    }
    else {
    document.write ("Is a consonant");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is `a` in your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable name is `chrctr` so you should check for `chrctr` and not `a`.

```
<script>
var chrctr = prompt("Enter a character");

    if (chrctr == 'a' || chrctr == 'e' || chrctr == 'i' || chrctr == 'o' || chrctr == 'u') {
        document.write("Is a Vowel");
    }
    else {
    document.write ("Is a consonant");
    }
</script>
```